# What are the actual stuff in the jmp_buf when using setjmp and longjmp?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, setjmp

setjmp() is supposed to save registers including "return address" and "stack pointer" into "jmp_buf". When I compile (both gcc and clang) and debug the following program under x86_64 with glibc, I cannot understand what is in the "jmp_buf" and where "return address" and "stack pointer" are located in the "jmp_buf".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <setjmp.h>

int main()
{
    int i;

    jmp_buf env;

    i = setjmp(env);

    printf("i = %d\n", i);

    if (i != 0) return;

    longjmp(env, 2);
    printf("Does this line get printed?\n");
}
```

When the program stops at a breakpoint before "printf("i = %d\n", i);", I tried gdb functionality: "p/x env"; however I cannot find the "return RIP" and "previous RSP" in this structure (env) which contains __jmpbuf and __saved_mask. Anyone knows how exactly these two functions work and what exactly they save under x86_64 with glibc (I use ubuntu 14.04)?

Comment: I saw several questions like this in stackoverflow.com, but the answers are usually "It depends on the architecture, OS, library and ABI..." or paste the standard. They are not what I would like to know.

Comment: Why don't you look at the implementation on your platform?  It's open source.  For example: https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/sysdeps/sh/____longjmp_chk.S - that's what longjmp calls into in glibc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Believe it or not, the contents of `jmp_buf` are *intentionally* meaningless. If you take a look at [the source to the x86_64 `setjmp()`](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/sysdeps/x86_64/setjmp.S), you'll note several references to `PTR_MANGLE`. This is an internal glibc macro which XORs a thread-local value against a register. This is used here in large part to ensure that developers do not rely on the layout of `jmpbuf` — it is considered an implementation detail, and may change between versions of libc.

If you want something readable, check out [the ucontext interface](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/ucontext.h.html).

Comment: I believe pointer mangling was introduced as a security feature rather than to hide the layout of jmpbuf.

Comment: @EmployedRussian You mean it can prevent some attack like stack overflow?

Comment: @WindChaser This is the only relevant link I could find: http://udrepper.livejournal.com/13393.html

Comment: Relevant mailing list thread: http://www.redhat.com/archives/rhl-devel-list/2006-September/msg00499.html